# How can I write this line in java 1.7

Tags: android, lambda, java-7

How can I write this line in java 1.7

```
client.getIndex("users").saveObjectAsync(j, user.getKey(), (jsonObject, e)->{});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Java 7 doesn't support lambdas.

Comment: You would replace the lambda with an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: yes, i know, i always get error bellow (jsonObject, e)->{} , what i want is to right equivalent of lambda expression in java 1.7

Comment: A bit more information might be useful. What is this line we are looking at? What does it belong to? What should it do? Seeing that you don't know how to port it to Java 7 I assume you didn't write the line but got it from some tutorial using Java 8 syntax? If so could you post the link?

Answer (score 1):

As @yshavit said you will have to replace the lambda expression with an annonymous class of a one-method interface.

```
interface LambdaReplacement {
    void someMethod(SomeJsonType jsonObject, AMysteriousE e);
}
```

Of course you need to know the types of the 2 inputs to the function ;)

Then in your code

```
client.getIndex("users").saveObjectAsync(j, user.getKey(), new LambdaReplacement() {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(SomeJsonType jsonObject, AMysteriousE e) {
        // whatever you want to actually do with it
        // or just nothing if you really want the behavior (jsonObject, e)->{}
    }
});
```